# freeradius not load clients.conf

Tags: freeradius

I am new in freeradius. I do not understand why radiusd does not take into account the clients.conf configuration file.

Extract from server logs :

```html
-including configuration file /etc/freeradius/clients.conf
----------------------------------------------------------
--------------------
-radiusd: #### Loading Clients ####
- client localhost {
  ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
  require_message_authenticator = no
  secret = <<< secret >>>
  nas_type = "other"
  proto = "*"
  limit {
   max_connections = 16
   lifetime = 0
   idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
 client localhost_ipv6 {
  ipv6addr = ::1
  require_message_authenticator = no
  secret = <<< secret >>>
  limit {
   max_connections = 16
   lifetime = 0
   idle_timeout = 30
  }
 }
```

and my clients.conf in /etc/freeradius/ :

```html
client dockernet 
{
    ipaddr = 172.17.0.0
    secret = testing123
    netmask = 24
    shortname = dockernet
}
```

Comment: This would probably be better on _Server Fault_.

Answer (score 0):

Ok  , i am running freeradius with docker.
I am modifing the wrong config file

Comment: i'm facing the same kind of problem. The modifications should be done to the /etc/freeradius/clients.conf files ryt?

Comment: Or should it be in etc/raddb/clients.conf file?

Comment: always debug with freeradius -X

Answer (score 0):

When FreeRADIUS starts up in debug mode, e.g.

```
radiusd -X
```

it prints out all the files it's reading. **You need to run this to check that the file you are editing is the one actually being used.**

Note that the configuration is often in different places depending on the installation.

Installed from source, the config is `/usr/local/etc/raddb` or `/etc/raddb`. On RedHat/CentOS based systems it's in `/etc/raddb`, and on Debian/Ubuntu systems it's in `/etc/freeradius` or `/etc/freeradius/3.0`.

For more advanced use cases, the `-d` option can tell FreeRADIUS to read its configuration from a different location, e.g.

```
radiusd -X -d /opt/raddb
```

This problem often comes about from having two installations, e.g. one installed from packages, and then installing from source on the same system.